# Requirejs add arguments to the script element

Tags: requirejs

is it possible to add arguments to the sctipt element

e.g.

```
<script 
    ...
    src="XX.js"
></script>
```

i want to add the argument hello="world" so this is added to the page:

```
<script 
    ... 
    src="XX.js"
    hallo="welt"
></script>
```

Reason: I have a js library ([aloha-editor](http://aloha-editor.org/)) which depends on a parameter for loading it's plugins (and the main functionallity is actuall in a plugin). However I only want to load the plugin when the user want's to edit and requirejs is the best choice since it is used at other parts in the application.

Comment: in case this get's lost for 5 years and is the top result for a desperate google. I found another way to configure my plugin (sucks to read this right ;))

Comment: How did you do it? I'm in the same position right now and looking for solutions :-)

Comment: the plugin (js library) has a varible which I can set, instead of the script arguments

Comment: I've been looking for something like that... could you explain a bit more, please? I've found another solution for the moment, but it's rather hackey.

Comment: are you talking about the aloha editor?

Comment: Yep :-) Sorry to not making it clear.

Comment: so it's about loading the plugins (like this: <script src="js/aloha/lib/aloha.js" data-aloha-plugins="common/format, costum/save"></script>) you can set the plugins in the config file like this: "(function(window, undefined) {
 if(window.Aloha === undefined || window.Aloha === null) {
  window.Aloha = {};
 }
 window.Aloha.settings = {
  plugins : {
   load : ['common/format', 'costum/save', 'common/highlighteditables', 'common/link']
  }
 };
})(window);" this will load the plugins! that's waht you are looking for?

Comment: Exactly that. I didn't find this nowhere. Thanks very much for the info :-)

Comment: np, (if you vote up my querstion, I get some points and maybe the question gets a bit more attention :))

Comment: @Stefan did you manage to avoid requre.js and jquery conflicts with aloha when using own version?

Comment: @Sylwia which conflicts?

Comment: In chrome sometimes I get this error http://pastebin.com/w5af0GCy so I guess it has something to do with require.js or jquery (I'm using latest one and aloha-full.js needs 1.8.2). In FF and Safari similar error.

Comment: I think I had this Problem when using require in my page, but hat a compiled Version of aloha, which has it's own Version of require which was different, then the one I used on my page. However it is hard to tell... maybe if you can Show me your code, I can tell you more

Answer (score 1):

If you are wrapping the aloha script in a define function you could pass arguments like this ([link](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-moduleconfig)):

```
//in main appfile
require.config({
    'config': {
        'aloha': {
            src: "XX.js",
            hallo: "welt"
        }
     }
});

//and in the aloha file
define(['module'], function (module) {
    var src = module.config().src,
        hallo = module.config().hallo;

    ... // the aloha code
});
```

There was also an alternative "simplified" syntax in the docs.

Edit: Maybe I misunderstood the question, if you where asking if it's possible to add html attributes to a script tag already on the page: `<script src='' data-src='xx.js' data-hallo='welt'></script>` is the new html5 syntax for adding custom attributes to tags, everything preceded by data- is correct syntax.